# Getting error as undefined variable on sitemap.xml file in CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I implemented `sitemap.xml` file. When I click on the link it is showing an error message.

Error:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://www.xxxx.com/</loc>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<!--
My code is looking quite different, but the principle is similar 
-->
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message: Undefined variable: data</p>
<p>Filename: views/sitemap.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 9</p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()</p>
<p>Filename: views/sitemap.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 9</p>
</div>
</urlset>
```

Here is my code.

Controller:

```
Class Seo extends CI_Controller {

function sitemap()
{

    $data = "";//select urls from DB to Array
    header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
    $this->load->view("sitemap",$data);
}
}
```

View:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml'); ?>
<?= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc><?= base_url();?></loc> 
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<!-- My code is looking quite different, but the principle is similar -->
<?php foreach($data as $url) { ?>
<url>
    <loc><?= base_url().$url ?></loc>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<?php } ?>
</urlset>
```

Config/routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['sitemap\.xml'] = "seo/sitemap";
```

Can anyone tell me what is the exact issue of that so that I can resolve my problem?

Comment: The `$data` variable in your controller looks like it may contain `""` which is then passed into the foreach loop in your View, could the problem be here?

Comment: @ThrowingSpoon yes from that only can you tell me how to resolve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
function sitemap()
{

    $data['items'] = "";//select urls from DB to Array
    $data['items'][0] = 'career';
    $data['items'][1] = 'testimonial';
    $data['items'][2] = 'portfolio';
    header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
    //print_r($data);
    $this->load->view("sitemap",$data);
}
```

View:

```
<?= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' ?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc><?= base_url();?></loc> 
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>

<?php 
   if(!empty($items)){
foreach($items as $url) { ?>
<url>
    <loc><?= base_url().$url ?></loc>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<?php } 
} ?>
```